# How can I check if multiple checkboxes are checked with JSF / AjaxBehaviorEvent

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have multiple checkboxes - they are given the same id, "choosen" in the xhtml view code.

I have added an Ajax event listener for them, like so:

```
<ui:repeat var="posts"
        value="#{postBacking.postsOverview.posts}">
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="choosen"
    styleClass="check-margin"
    value="#{posts.choosen}" rendered="#{posts.declined =='No'}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{postsBacking.isPostsChosen}" event="click" render="@form" execute="@form"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</ui:repeat>
```

In the listener method in my backingBean, I would like to check if any of these checkboxes are checked, and then set a button disabled if no checkboxes are marked - and enabled if one or more is set.

But how do I get hold of the values of all checkboxes - can I use the AjaxBehaviorEvent objet for that or is there some other way?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Nothing really, I have googled and googled and still haven't found anything about how to check if those checkboxes are checked. I can't figure out if I can use that event object and withdraw the values from that or ... it's really a blur to me

Comment: The same way you iterate over things now. But server side in java

Comment: As suggested by Noah, in your listener method you'd need to add java code that loops through your posts and determines if there is a post chosen. If so set the button disabled `false`. In your xhtml there even is no button present. Please edit your question to include the button and your attempt to solve the problem. For now your question comes along like "please write the code for me" which is not likely to get the answer you await.

Comment: Yeah, I know - part of the problem is I cannot find out how to get value of those checkboxes. I am not sure you understand :-/ How exactly can I get hold of the checkbox values on the java server side? Can I take the values from the event object? If I iterate through the postBacking.postsOverview.posts, surely I won't get the latest checkbox value that the user has set?

Comment: You ask, why not TRY and be sure?

Answer (score 1):

While processing the ajax event listener, the checkbox values should normally have been applied to your data model where you can look up the state of user choice. Depending on that state, simply toggle a boolean bean property which disables the command button:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private List<Post> posts;

    private boolean buttonDisabled = true;

    public void ajaxEventListener(BehaviorEvent e) {
        boolean anythingChosen = false;
        for (Post post : posts) {
            if (post.isChosen() && "No".equals(post.getDeclined())) {
                anythingChosen = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // or alternatively using the stream api:
        // anythingChosen = posts.stream().filter(Post::isChosen).map(Post::getDeclined)
        //     .anyMatch("No"::equals);

        setButtonDisabled(!anythingChosen);
    }
    // getters, setters ...
}
```

Using the following form, the command button is disabled as long as no checkbox is checked:

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat var="post" value="#{myBean.posts}">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{post.chosen}">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{myBean.ajaxEventListener}" render="@form" execute="@form"/>
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </ui:repeat>

    <h:commandButton action="#{myBean.doSomething()}" value="doSomething"
        disabled="#{myBean.buttonDisabled}" />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `valueChangeListener` rather than using `listener` and `event` attributes. The `valueChangeListener` will be triggered every time you check/uncheck the checkbox.

To get hold of the values when the`valueChangeListener` is invoked, you can loop through the `postBacking.postsOverview.posts` to see if any value is checked.

Don't forget to update the button on `<f:ajax render="@form btnId"/>` to enable/ disable it.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up, I will try using the valueChangeListener instead :-) How do I see if any of the values are checked in the checkboxes? I really can't figure that out :-/

Comment: Follow Selaron's answer, that should solve your question.